# Trying to write java code that uses a switch to select data from sqlite database

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I am trying to query data from the database using JDBC, but I cant get the SELECT SUM() to work on the third switch case. All the other cases and SELECT amount on the third case work just fine, but when I try to use SELECT SUM(amount) it gives the error "no such column: 'amount'".

Here is my code:

```
package net.sqlitetutorial;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;


public class SQLMain {

    
    private Connection connect() {
        
        String url = "jdbc:sqlite:C://sqlite/db/test.db";
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return conn;
    }

    
    
    

public void selectAll(){
        String sql = "SELECT name, amount FROM names ORDER BY amount desc";
        
        try (Connection conn = this.connect();
             Statement stmt  = conn.createStatement();
             ResultSet rs    = stmt.executeQuery(sql)){
            
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString("name") +  "\t" + 
                                   rs.getInt("amount"));
                                   
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

public void selectNames(){
        String sql = "SELECT name FROM names ORDER BY name";
        
        try (Connection conn = this.connect();
             Statement stmt  = conn.createStatement();
             ResultSet rs    = stmt.executeQuery(sql)){
            
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString("name"));
                                   
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }


public void selectAmount(){
        String sql = "SELECT sum(amount) FROM names";
        
        try (Connection conn = this.connect();
             Statement stmt  = conn.createStatement();
             ResultSet rs    = stmt.executeQuery(sql)){
            
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getInt("amount"));
                                   
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    
   
   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SQLMain app = new SQLMain();
        
    int number;

      
      Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

      
      System.out.println("Choose one by entering a number:\n 1. List all ordered by most popular name first\n 2. List names in alphabetical order");
      number = console.nextInt();

      
      switch (number)
      {
    case 1 :
        app.selectAll();
    break;
    

    case 2 :
    app.selectNames();
    break;

    case 3 :
    app.selectAmount();
    break;

    default:
    System.out.println("Invalid input");
    
}


    }

}
```

This is the error it gives out:
`no such column: 'amount'`

Comment: Can you improve your post to display some more details like the code line and the whole error report? At first glance I would say your test.db lacks the attribute `amount`, but it's also possible that some errors before will show problems with connecting to the database itself or some other errors...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this statement:

```
SELECT sum(amount) FROM names
```

there is no column returned by the name `amount`.

You must set an alias to the column returned:

```
SELECT sum(amount) AS amount FROM names
```

Or, without aliasing the column, you could get its value by its index which is `1`:

```
System.out.println(rs.getInt(1));
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because the result contains `SUM(amount)` and not the column `amount`.

You can for instance fix this by changing the query to

```
"SELECT sum(amount) AS amount FROM names"
```

or getting the result by index

```
rs.getInt(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query really doesn't have a an `amount` column in it - it has `sum(amount)`. You could use an alias as [forpas' answer suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65782216/2422776), or just the index (remember - column indexes in JDBC are one-based):

```
while (rs.next()) {
    System.out.println(rs.getInt(1));
}
```